# problem with \NewList in bidi package

Tags: xetex, bidi, xepersian

The macro `\NewList` is defined in `biditools.sty` (originally defined in `lollipop`) as:

```
\def\bidi@csarg#1#2{\expandafter#1\csname#2\endcsname}
\def\NewList:#1 {\bidi@csarg\newtoks{#1}\global\csname#1\endcsname{}}
```

which is different from that defined in `easylist.sty`.

It should be noted that the macro `\NewList` is not used anywhere in `bidi` or `xepersian` packages,
however, in the following code it causes failure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{easylist}
\usepackage[fontsloadable]{xepersian} % option is required because
                   % xepersian 21.8 and 21.9 prevent loading fonts
                   % with the string "HM" in their font name.
\settextfont[Scale=1.44]{Amiri}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1.44]{Psychedelia HM}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{easylist}\NewList
§ تراز اول --- \lr{first level}
§§§ تراز سوم --- \lr{third level}
\end{easylist}
\end{document}
```

The error message is:

```
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/loadingorder
-xepersian.def)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/footnote-xep
ersian.def)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xepersian/article-xepe
rsian.def)) (./easylist-test.aux)
! Use of \NewList doesn't match its definition.
l.11 §
       تراز اول --- \lr{first level}
? h
If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.

?
```

Is it safe to comment the macro `\NewList` out in `biditools.sty`?
If yes, is there any (internal or external) command in LaTeX that
I can use instead of `\NewList`?

Comment: The `\NewList` command is defined to *require* `:` after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what `\NewList` is supposed to do as defined in `biditools`.

Its definition, as it stands, *requires* it to be followed by a colon.

You can recover the `easylist` definition, but this might cause problems if the redefined `\NewList` is needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{easylist}
\let\easylistNewList\NewList
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1.44]{Amiri}
\AtBeginDocument{\let\NewList\easylistNewList}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{easylist}\NewList
§ تراز اول
§§§ تراز سوم
\end{easylist}
\end{document}
```

You might want not to do the second `\let` and use `\easylistNewList` instead.